# performance anaysis (select in loop vs function call in loop )

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

i will like to ask a performance related question here my question is which approach is best

1 adding subquery in loop

```
declare
test varchar2(50);

FOR Lcntr IN 1..20

LOOP

   update emp set empno='50'  where empname=test;

END LOOP;
```

2 adding function call in loop or making the function of the above query and calling it in loop

```
declare

test varchar2(50);

FOR Lcntr IN 1..20
LOOP

  temp:=update('argument');

END LOOP;
```

Comment: Since the loop construction is the same in both cases, I'm not sure what it has to do with the question. Couldn't your question be simplified by removing the loops?

Answer (score 1):

If your function `update` just call the same sql update, it dosen't matter are you call it directly of from stored function. 
In common the best way is use one sql statement (update or merge) for update whole dataset what you need.

But you update are look like strange: 
In first pl/sql block you declare variable `test`. And test is equal `null`. And after that you try update table by comparing with `null` - no any rows will be affected.

In second pl\sql block you declare variable `test` too, but use varable `temp`. It will raise error in compilation.

Comment: @micheal thanks for the reply   its just dummy code but my question is in overall performance which one is better for large chunk of data

Comment: @fawad hi. But its not clear where the difference? In first variant you call update directly, in second as I understand you call the same update from function. If there is only a differ then, its dosen't matter are you called udpate or call function witch call update. in both case as I know the bottle neck(if one exists) is switching context between pl/SQL and SQL processer, but it will be used in both way.